# Scala dependency in Spark/Pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies

I want to install Spark in a machine and I don't know if I need Scala as a dependency.
I have installed Java (1.8) as the documentation saids. But I don't know If I need any other dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Scala is included in Spark's distribution, so for using Scala in Spark REPL you don't need to install Scala. Here are scala jars included.

If you are setting up IDE for Spark project then you will need Scala as dependency.
[image]